# Is markdown formatting allowed in an Area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

Is markdown formatting supported/allowed in site definitions for Area 51 proposals? More specifically, are we allowed to use hyperlinks?

I'm putting together a proposal for Web Original Series and wanted to use [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WebOriginal) as a reference in my site's definition.

[image: Who is this site for?]

Comment: You might want to add _RWBY_ to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR:

No.

### Step 1

[image]

### Step 2

[image]

### Step 3

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know if making a test post would be frowned upon.